# How to detect if user pressed cancel button or selected root (primary disk) with java.awt.FileDialog in MAC OS?

Tags: java, swing, filedialog

Does somebody knows how to detect if user selected cancel button or root disk in java.awt.FileDialog in Mac OS (10.6 - Snow Leopard)????

I have the below code:

```
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "true"); 
FileDialog fd = new FileDialog(this);  
fd.setDirectory(_projectsBaseDir.getPath());  
fd.setLocation(50,50); fd.setVisible(true);  
File selectedFile = new File(fd.getFile()); 
System.setProperty("apple.awt.fileDialogForDirectories", "false");
```

But if user selects primary disk on the left panel (below Devices), the selection returns null, I cannot diferentiate if user selected primary disk or presssed the cancel button. (both actions return null).

Answer (score 0):

If it's possible to use Swing, I'd highly recommend using JFileChooser.  Then your code would look like this:

```
JFileChooser fc = new JFileChooser();
fc.setCurrentDirectory(_projectsBaseDir.getPath());
fc.setLocation(50,50);
int ret = fc.showOpenDialog(this); // Use .showSaveDialog(this) for save dialog
if(ret == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    File selectedFile = fc.getSelectedFile();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I need to used native dialogs, that's why I am using java.awt.FileDialog.